# Nested virtualisation: unable to change the power state - Intel VT-x disabled

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, microsoft, azure

I have a problem installing virtualbox on ubuntu which is installed on microsoft azure. I get the following error:

> Unable to change the power state of the virtual machine: this host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.
> Intel VT-x may be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or if the host has not been rebooted since changing this setting.

But I don't have access to BIOS to activate virtualization.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to enable nested virtualization. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-template-vm-using-script?tabs=powershell